# Вылетает приложение при использовании setMyLocation

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Если использовать `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` и дать приложению разрешение на использование местоположения, то приложение просто вылетает при запуске.

[image: Вот ошибка]

[image: Код]

Comment: Нет-нет-нет! Не надо скринов, надо код и логи ошибки текстом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `NPE` т.к. переменная `mMap` не инициализирована. А неинициализирована она на момент обращения, т.к. инициализируется асинхронно и обращаться к ней надо в колбэке, который вызовется в момент окончания инициализации карты